# Dreamweaver CS5.5 and Fancybox 1.3.4

Tags: javascript, css, fancybox

I'm using Dreamweaver CS5.5 and Fancybox 1.3.4. 
I've placed 4 images in a main div (2 in each row) and they fitted perfectly together (I don't want gaps as together the 4 images form one pic) till I applied fancybox to them. 
Now there's a horizontal margin of about 20px between the 2 rows and I can't find where it's coming from. Any ideas? Do I need to paste the code here? 
Be gentle – I'm primarily a print designer, so I'm learning dev as I go along. Thanks.

I have this in the head tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>; <link href="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> <link href="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

And this before the closing body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function($){
    var addToAll = false;
    var gallery = false;
    var titlePosition = 'inside';
    $(addToAll ? 'img' : 'img.fancybox').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        var title = $this.attr('title');
        var src = $this.attr('data-big') || $this.attr('src');
        var a = $('<a href="#" class="fancybox"></a>').attr('href', src).attr('title', title);
        $this.wrap(a);
    });
    if (gallery)
        $('a.fancybox').attr('rel', 'fancyboxgallery');
    $('a.fancybox').fancybox({
        titlePosition: titlePosition
    });
});
$.noConflict();
```

Comment: Adding a minimal example of your code that expresses your issue will help others determine what is wrong.

Comment: Ok thanks Steve, I have these in the head tag:
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

    <link href="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="jquery.fancybox-1.3.4/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"> and these before the closing body tag:

Comment: Go ahead and edit your question to put your details in there.  I'm not a dreamweaver person, but those details will help the dreamweaver people figure out what is wrong.

Comment: Thanks Steve, not sure if I did that right!

Answer (score 0):

In the code you posted, you are not closing your javascript. This might be the problem. So after $.noConflict(); add

```
</script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks! 
I've just sorted the issue out now. Had <figure> tags around the images, so deleted those and everything's gone back into place. Phew!

Answer (score 0):

You could also override the CSS property by setting the margin and padding to the parent elements depending on the markup of the site.

Is there any way you could show us the HTML of that section?